# How do I install a previous version of build tools in addition to the sdk?

Tags: android, android-studio

I trying to build an android project that needs a previous version of the Android SDK and build tools: https://github.com/googlevr/gvr-android-sdk.git (android-24)

In Android studio I went to the SDK manager and installed the previous version:
[image]

But when I went to try build the project with grandle I get this error:

```
Failed to find Build Tools revision 24.0.0
```

Looks like sdk manager didnt install the Build Tools. How do I do this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So this is a bug/missing feature of android-studio?

I had to run the SDK manager directly from: `C:\Users\<User Name>\AppData\Local\Android\sdk\` and in there I could see the build tools broken out separately from the sdks. Unless I'm missing something I didn't see that in studio. Installing from SDK Manager worked:
[image]

Just curious, how is this process automated? How can I have a project automatically download all its dependancies without have to run grandle in studio, have it throw and error, download missing dependancies, and try again?

Answer (score 50):

Show Package Details under SDK Tools tab gives you more info on obtaining the older build tools.
[image]

Comment: And where do I find this "SDK Tools tab"?

Comment: @trollkotze You'll find it by clicking `Configure` on the startup screen, then `SDK Manager`

Answer (score 0):

Only delete the folder `C:\Users\your_user\AppData\Roaming\Corona Labs` and install `solar2d/coronaSDK` again.