# Godot for .NET Android Export

Tags: c#, android, .net, godot4

I am trying to learn to use Godot while at the same time using C# as the scripting language, I've followed along several tutorials and have been successful in converting the GDScript into C# in all of them so far, however, I've run into what may be an impasse... when trying to export to Android the provided export files are only for Windows or Linux... however when I downloaded the non-.NET version of Godot (4.0.3 if that matters) I also get android, ios and web export templates.

Godot .NET/mono:
[image]

Godot:

[image]

Am I missing something? Do I need to manually create those export templates? Can I download them somewhere? Or does Godot .NET just not able to export to anything but Windows or Linux (I highly doubt this as it lets me do all of the steps to export to Android, minus the missing templates)!

Answer (score 1):

Well, instead of deleting this question, I'll leave this here for the next one who comes across this issue, but you can just copy the android export templates from the non-.NET version of Godot to the .NET version and it all seems to work just fine... that is, I was able to debug on my Android phone directly from Godot.

BTW: if you also run into the "Target platform not yet implemented error" error and not being able to export/run your app remotely from Godot on your Android device (black screen). Try installing the correct Android build tools version, which is:
`33.0.2` [<- install this exact version](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44458834/550975). You may still get the errors but it will now push correctly to your phone.

More details: https://github.com/godotengine/godot/issues/55133#issuecomment-1589054217